# Reducing System Volume

Tags: macos

How do I halve the system volume?

I want one bar (out of sixteen) of volume to be as loud as half a bar etc.

How does one do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to do this, as you can't set a volume restriction (as you can with iOS) and no apps that I know of can do this. One thing you can do, however, is hold down **option** and **shift** as you change the volume (Lion or newer, including El Capitan) and it will change in one-quarter-notch increments, allowing for the greater precision I think you desire.